# SQL statement with multiple syntax to EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to replicate this SQL statement

```
  SELECT TOP(5) Activity, COUNT(*)     
  FROM [Table]
  GROUP BY Activity
  ORDER BY count(Activity) DESC
```

to EF Core in my MVC .NET Core application.

So far I am able to display all the data I need with out the syntax(group, order, top) with the following code:

```
var activity = list.Select(f => f.Activity.Name).Distinct();
```

I've tried using `Take()`, but that just gives me the top rows in the table, and I can't seem to get `OrderByDescending()` to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on You SQL Query you need to perform like this.

> Sample Class

```
    public class Activity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

> Controller method

With Sample data, you need to change accordingly

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {           

            List<Activity> lstActivity = new List<Activity>();
            lstActivity.Add(new Activity() { Name = "A" });
            lstActivity.Add(new Activity() { Name = "B" });
            lstActivity.Add(new Activity() { Name = "A" });
            lstActivity.Add(new Activity() { Name = "A" });
            lstActivity.Add(new Activity() { Name = "C" });
            lstActivity.Add(new Activity() { Name = "A" });
            lstActivity.Add(new Activity() { Name = "D" });
            lstActivity.Add(new Activity() { Name = "A" });
            lstActivity.Add(new Activity() { Name = "E" });
            lstActivity.Add(new Activity() { Name = "A" });
            lstActivity.Add(new Activity() { Name = "F" });
            lstActivity.Add(new Activity() { Name = "1" });
            lstActivity.Add(new Activity() { Name = "G" });
            lstActivity.Add(new Activity() { Name = "G" });
            lstActivity.Add(new Activity() { Name = "1" });

            var activity = lstActivity.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => new { Name = x.Key, Count = x.Count() }).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Count).Take(5).ToList();
            return View(activity);
        }
```

> Output

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you Jishan! This worked perfect. Thanks for all the detail!

Comment: Welcome brother :)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to perform `OrderByDescending()`, after that you can use `take()` which gives you top records after performing order by.

```
var activity = dataList.Select(f =>f.Activity).Distinct().OrderByDescending(p=>p).Take(5);
```

Comment: What about the groupby syntax? The results I am getting seem to be ordered by name and not count.

Comment: as you can see, `Distinct()`, it will return only unique record.